# HAKMEM 39: Repetition-less digit strings

Tags: sequences-and-series

From [here](http://www.inwap.com/pdp10/hbaker/hakmem/number.html#item39).

This particular item deals with excluding strings that have a consecutive repeated sequence. That is, ab*b*a and abcab*ab*c both have doubles whereas abcabacba doesn't. When working in base $2$, the number of sequences is easily seen to be finite.

**0**
**1**

*00*
**01**
**10**
*11*

**010**
*011*
*100*
**101**

*0100*
*0101*
*1010*
*1011*

They also mention that base $10$ is known to be infinite. In addition, base $3$ seems to be infinite, as evidenced by [this exponentially-growing pattern](http://oeis.org/A006156).

My question is: how can you prove that the number of repetition-free sequences is infinite for base $b \ge 3$?

Comment: If you can prove it is infinite for base $b$, then it is infinite for any base $b'\geq b$. Now look up Thue's sequence. (It may be called something else, but Thue gave an infinite squarefree word in three letters).

Comment: P.S. The more common term is "squarefree words", not "repetition-less digit strings". That might also help with internet searches.

Comment: You mean the Thue-Morse sequence? But that's in binary...

Comment: No, I mean the sequence that Thue produced for an alphabet with three letters. E.g., [Wikipedia's entry on "Squarefree word"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squarefree_word).

Comment: Arturo means what Arturo says.

Comment: @Arturo: Ah, neat! Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This paper](http://www.cs.umb.edu/~offner/files/thue.pdf) gives a very nice elementary presentation of the Thue-Morse sequence and in particular of the result that there is an infinite square-free sequence over an alphabet of three letters.

Answer (score 7):

Thue proved that any alphabet on three or more letters contains an infinite [squarefree word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squarefree_word). An example due to Leech (*A problem on strings of beads*, Math. Gazette **41** (1957) 277– 278):

On the alphabet that contains $a$, $b$, and $c$, define $w_1$ to be a word beginning with $a$ (say, $w_1=a$).

Given $w_n$, define $w_{n+1}$ by replacing each occurrence of $a$ in $w_n$ by $abcbacbcabcba$; every occurrence of $b$ in $w_n$ by $bcacbacabcacb$; and every occurrence of $c$ by $cabacbabcabac$.

Then $w_n$ converges to an infinite squarefree word, which begins
$$abcbacbcabcbabcacbacabcacbcabacbabcabacbcacbacabcacb\ldots$$